# PHP getting csv data, undefined offset error

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to retrieve column data from a csv file. The first two columns return fine, but for some reason I get `Notice: Undefined offset: 2` when I try to reference the 3rd column of csv data. Here is what I believe to be the relevant code in question:

```
$handle = fopen($csv_file, 'r');

while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1024, $delimiter)) !== false) {
    echo $fileop[0]."<br/>";
    echo $fileop[1]."<br/>";
    echo $fileop[2]."<br/>";    //error occurs this line
}
```

The CSV file text:

```
THE GOLD CONNECTION,1760,2014-06-01
PINEFOREST JEWELRY,3034.25,2014-06-05
AMBERS DESIGN,2034.75,z
GOLD FALCON CUSTOM JEWELERS (PORT),78,
SUE'S JEWELRY,120,
JC JEWELERS,274,
ALTER'S GEM JEWELRY,74,
STALL JEWELERS,38,
ELEGANT JEWELERS,174,
ELEGANT JEWELERS,206,
SALEM'S JEWELERS,406,
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: *Hm...* You don't have ending commas for the first three, but then the rest do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- commas don't seem to have an effect

Comment: Did you try getting rid of all the commas at the end, or did you make them all ending with a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_key_exists to verify that third index exists:

```
while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1024, $delimiter)) !== false) {
    echo  $fileop[0]."<br/>";
    echo $fileop[1]."<br/>";
    echo array_key_exists(2, $fileop) ? $fileop[2]."<br/>" : "<br/>";    //error occurs this line
}
```